# Place char on another char in tkinter Label widget

Tags: python, tkinter, label, character

is there a way of placing character onto another character in python `tkinter` `Label`? If not is it possible with `Text` widget?

Comment: Not that I am aware of but someone else might know if its possible. Why do you want to overlap characters?

Comment: Yes, technically. You can use the `.place()` geometry manager to place two separate widgets with the same content over top of each other, but this is messy and could generate dozens of extra lines for something so simple. Is there a reason why you want to do this? There may be a simpler answer to achieving your desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks for response :) I want to use Segoe MDL2 Assets for creating some icons.

Comment: @JakubBláha So why do you need to overlap characters for that? Or do you mean replace?

Comment: And I think its not possible with place manager due to fact that `Label` has some background that would overwrite the content of the other `Label`.

Comment: I need for example icon of home and place checkmark on top of it.

Comment: @EthanField:  `place` won't do what the OP is asking. Labels have a solid background, so placing one on top of another with `place` will hide what is on the lower widget.

Comment: If what you want is to place a checkmark on top of an icon, is it really two characters you want to superimposed or it could be a picture (the icon) and a character? If it is the last, it can be done with a label, otherwise, you'll need to use a canvas as Bryan Oakley said.

Comment: I need to place char on char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible with either the `Label` or`Text` widget. You can do it with the `Canvas` widget, however.